# Zend framework why nee to add Application_Form or Application__Model

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using zend framework version 1.12

I am looking in online tutorial there no need to add prefix like Application_Form or Application__Model before class for creating form and model.

But I need to add otherwise nothing works.

What is the issue and how to resolve it?

I were trying to implement it
http://zendgeek.blogspot.in/2009/07/zend-framework-building-complete.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it's the syntax that `zend` uses to identify from where you are using the `resource`,

for example the `zend app` structure will be like,

```
├───configs
├───controllers
├───forms
├───layouts
│   └───scripts
├───models
└───views
    ├───helpers
    └───scripts
```

which will all be under `Application` Folder,

So if you want to use a form You need to use `Application_Form_formname`
which suggests you are using form from `application->Form` folder,

same with the model , you have to use  `Application_Model_modelname,`

You can create your own folders and directory and use them,

For example
create a directory under `model`  named `DbTable`,

Then you can use following to access `models` located under `DbTable`,

```
Application_Model_DbTable_ModelName
```

Hope That Helps, For Info use Official [DOC](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)

**UPDATE**

you can use any third party classes easily, for example i have used mongo db's third party module,

like this,

```
class Application_Model_Post extends Shanty_Mongo_Document
```

and in my application i have specified autoloader as

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Shanty_"
```

and the source library of mongo is placed under library named as Shanty, so that can be used easily.

Comment: What I have to do if I want to use any third party class?

Comment: see update, you can use any third party class like that and you will find tutorials of them according the third party you want to use.